# The earliest shortest match location

Tags: algorithm

Assume you have a function `matchWithMagic` that returns a Boolean value for a given string. You don't know any detail how it do it but you know the result of `true` means "Match". Assuming the complexity of this function is linear in time and space to the size of input string.

Now the question is to implement a function that for a given string, that will return an pair of integers, namely `pos` and `len` such that `matchWithMagic(substring(inputstring,pos,len))`  matches and `pos` is the least number that this can be true (earliest match). When `pos` is known, `len` is the least number for a match (shortest match, with a lower priority). There are no requirement on efficiency but the answer should includes performance analyse.

For example, suppose the magic function return true for input strings contains "Good Guy!" or "Bad Guy!" your function should return `pos=5,len=8` for "Good Bad Guy!".

Preferred languages is C/C++/Java/JavaScript/C#/Basic, but other languages are OK.

**UPDATE**

A trivial answer has now been posted. I hope a more efficient solution could appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the function is black-box, I'm not sure you can do better than this:

```
for (int pos = 0:n)
for (int len = 0:(n-pos))
  if (matchWithMagic(substring(inputstring,pos,len)))
    return {pos, len};
return null;
```

Which I believe is `O(n^3)` (assuming `matchWithMagic` is `O(n)`).

Comment: Actually I should say this is the right answer; however the purpose of this post is not for a trivial solution. I really want to see whether better solutions (more efficient) exists or not. Anyway, if no better answer appear in a week I have to mark this one.

Comment: I am sorry after clear thinking about it I realise this is not a good question. If there are no assumptions on the black-box, I believe this is the best answer we can actually have.